# Getting a database value using textbox

Tags: c#, sql

```
private void dosomething(String q)
    {
        try
        {
            cn.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = q;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cn.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            cn.Close();
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
 if (textBox1.Text == String.Empty || textBox3.Text == String.Empty)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please fill up all the textboxes");
        }
        else {
            string studentNo = textBox1.Text;
            string sql = "SELECT Name FROM StudentInfo where StudentNo=@student_no";
            using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql,cnn))
            {
                command.Parameters.Add("@student_no", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = studentNo;

            }
            string q = "insert into Issue([Name],[Book_Title],[Date_Borrowed]) values('" + studentNo + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + DateTime.Now.ToString("M/d/yyyy") + "')";
            dosomething(q);
            MessageBox.Show("Success");

        }
```

Im trying to create a program where a student will enter their Student No. in a textbox and then the entered student number will get their Name stored another table seperate from the table in which the actual storing will take place.

Their actual Name should get entered in the table instead of the student no. but this code doesnt do that. It enters the text from the student number entered in the textbox itself

Comment: But you don't execute and get the value of `Name` in your `SELECT` statement? You should _always_ use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) as you did for your `SELECT` statement. This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: You haven't execute the query 'SELECT Name FROM StudentInfo...`

Comment: And do **not** store your `DateTime` values as a `string`. Pass their values _directly_ (`DateTime.Now` in your case) in a parameterized query. Read: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Soner pointed out you didn't execute the `SELECT` statement to get the `Name`.

You should be getting the `Name` like;

```
string name = string.Empty;

using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql,cnn))
{
    command.Parameters.Add("@student_no", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = studentNo;
    object returnValue = Command.ExecuteScalar();
    name = Convert.ToString(returnValue);
}
```

Then this value should go to the `INSERT` command.

```
string q = "insert into Issue([Name],[Book_Title],[Date_Borrowed]) values('" + name + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + DateTime.Now.ToString("M/d/yyyy") + "')";
dosomething(q);
```

Also please use parameterized query for the `INSERT` command.